# Count occurrences of names from a list in a text columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a `df.Description` Column, which has text such as

> "shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) XL",

where the color is always in brackets.

I then have a list of colors:

```
Colours = ('Blue',
 'Orange',
 'Green',
 'Red',
 'Purple',
 'Brown',
 'Pink',
 'Gray',
 'Olive',
 'Cyan',
 'Black',
 'White')
```

My aim is  to count the occurrences of each word in the list Colours alongside the word "t-shirt" in that `df.Description` column.

Basically I need to know which t-shirt colour has been sold the most so I need to count for the colors when there is also the word t-shirt in `df.Description`.

Comment: Are you working with dataframes ?\

Comment: Convert to a list and use Counter ```from collections import Counter``` and use that

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply()` and `value_counts()` to calculate the number of occurrance of colors. I would also suggest you to do text preprocessing like converting to small letters and removing punctuations.:

```
def find_col(x):
  Colours = ['Blue',
 'Orange',
 'Green',
 'Red',
 'Purple',
 'Brown',
 'Pink',
 'Gray',
 'Olive',
 'Cyan',
 'Black',
 'White']

  for col in Colours:
    if (col in x) and ('t-shirt' in x):
      return col + ' t-shirt'
  return 'Not a tshirt'


df['Colors'] = df['Description'].apply(find_col)

df['Colors'].value_counts()
```

Comment: This is brilliant Prakash! Thanks a lot

Comment: @LockedDown [You should accept a useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).